# After changing my Ionic application package name, splash screen is not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My problem is that after changing my Ionic project package name, the splash screen is not shown. If I rename the package name back to the old one (the one which I created the project with) through the Command Line Interface, it works fine again. However, using the new package name again, the splash screen is not displayed. I also tried splash screen plugin, but the problem is still not solved. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you tried removing the platform and re-adding it once again & building it?

Comment: hey i tried to remove platform and add again android platform but its was  not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How did you rename your app?
The name of your app is in several files so if you missed one that could be having knock on effects.

Comment: inside Java - Eclipse --> Right Click on my project --> Android Tools --> Rename Application Package. and after rename my splash screen not display. but i again rename my old one package name then splash screen will be shown.